# Using Moq to Mock a class with Unity IoC dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, unity-container

So, we have a custom mock class already that we created manually. -- it works great for our existing tests, but we also want to be able to verify that given methods were called on it (i.e. `mock.Verify`). -- I could just add a million booleans, one for each method and property in our mock class to verify that each method was called with the correct parameters, but this would get really ugly and hairy, and ultimately wouldn't have the same fidelity as using Moq.

If the mock class didn't have injected dependencies, I could just create a new one using `new Mock<MyMockObject>()`, and everything would work fine. -- But it also has dependencies injected automatically by Unity, so in this case, it would fail, and leave those properties as null.

Is there any way to make the two play nicely together? -- Any way to tell Moq to use Unity to create the class? -- Or any way to tell Unity to populate the class created by Moq? -- Should I be using a different mocking library that knows about Unity?

Here's a Console Application example of what I'd like to get working; right now the `Bar` property comes in as null (because Moq doesn't know about my unity container):

```
public class Bar: IBar
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Foobar: IFoobar
{
    public virtual string Foo { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public virtual IBar Bar { get; protected set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var uc = new UnityContainer())
        {
            // Injected by specific unit test:
            uc.RegisterInstance<IBar>(new Bar() { Text = "Hello World!" });

            // This way works, but I can't verify if methods get called.
            Console.WriteLine
            (
                uc.Resolve<Foobar>().Bar.Text
            );

            // This way I can verify if certain methods were called, but "Bar" will never be
            // populated, so the following will throw a NullReferenceException.
            Console.WriteLine
            (
                new Mock<Foobar>().Object.Bar.Text
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Guys, please don't get hung up on the interop between Unity and Moq, or on unit testing philosophy. -- Obviously this code and scenario is very simplified. -- I'm asking in general on how to make something work.

If it helps you to remove Unity from the situation and think of this question as a Moq only question, that's fine, at that point, the question would be:

If I have a pre-constructed Mock Object (it comes from a factory, or magic fairies, or my uncle gave it to me, it doesn't matter, I have an existing mock object): how do I create a Mock wrapper around that existing object instance to intercept the calls that are made to it?  (Mainly, I want to intercept in order to verify that certain methods were called with certain parameters, or certain properties were called, etc., via the Verify keyword.)

So, instead of `new Mock<IFoo>()`, I want to do something like `Mock.GetWrapper(existingFooInstance)`. -- Is this possible? -- It looks like there used to be libraries that did this, but what I've found seems to be unmaintained, and not super useful.

Answer (score 0):

so what exactly do you want to test there? Your `Foobar` class? Then you should mock everything **but** this class.
If you want to do verifications on the Bar property, you could mock it like this:

```
var barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
barMock.SetupGet(x => x.Text).Returns("Hello World");
uc.RegisterInstance<IBar>(barMock.Object);
```

After that, you can check if anything on the barMock was called:

```
barMock.VerifyGet(x => x.Text);
```

On another note, if you do unit test you should isolate your class under test as much as possible, so using Unity to actually create it doesn't really seem like the best idea. In our environment we usually inject everything into the constructor, which would allow us to create the Foobar Object in the Unit Test without any "Unity Magic". Maybe you could think about that instead of using the `[Dependency]` Attribute.

Comment: Obviously I don't want to test the mock classes. -- That doesn't even make sense. -- What I want to test is the whole rest of my application; that's why we have mocked versions of our dependencies!

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you would provide a sample of testing "the whole rest of my application". There really isn't anything else people can tell you other than what is in this answer given the example you have provided. You don't have any business logic to test in `Foobar`. So, if you are not testing `Foobar` (which the above is a good solution for), what is it you are testing? Unclear how Moq fits in the picture here if `Foobar` is a hand-made mock class - you can either use Moq to mimic the class or use a hand made mock class, not both.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if this is *unit* testing (unclear from your question), using a DI container such as Unity is overkill - you are only supposed to have 1 *real* class for any given scenario, and the rest should typically be mocks or stubs that are created with the `new` keyword.

Secondly, constructor injection should always be the first choice for injecting dependencies. For one, you can ensure they are never `null` for a given scenario, which simplifies the code that uses the field/property.

```
public class Foobar: IFoobar
{
    public FooBar(IBar bar)
    {
        // using a guard clause ensures your dependency can
        // never be null.
        if (bar == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public virtual string Foo { get; set; }

    public virtual IBar Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

Also, IMO using a container's built-in attributes (such as `[Dependency]`) to inject properties is a bad choice because it means that your *application* is dependent on a specific DI container. Furthermore, property injection should only be used for *optional* dependencies (that is, dependencies that are ignored by your application if they are null). So, use constructor injection for required dependencies. If they are optional, either find a convention-based way to inject the dependency, or use a *custom* attribute (from your application) to signal injection which you can also use for tests. Then you don't need to involve a DI container in testing.

> I recommend you read the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net). Clearly, you are doing something wrong if you think your unit tests need a DI container and you believe that using constructor injection is somehow "more difficult" than property injection. I can't tell you exactly what is wrong though because your example is oversimplified and doesn't demonstrate *why* you think you need a container for unit tests.
>
> Dependency Injection is about making an application loosely-coupled, which usually involves significantly limiting (and refactoring) the application design to make it follow the DI pattern. The use of a container is completely optional. This makes it extremely simple to compose your *application* with a DI container, and compose unit tests manually. In fact, putting a DI container in your unit tests only serves to make your tests more difficult to understand.

Comment: We have multiple projects using the same class libraries, and we're injecting certain behaviors into them using Unity (for example, the way the web front end determines who the current user is, is different from how the background service does it -- and both of those are different from how the Unit Tests will fake it). -- Unity containers simplifies a lot of this for us, including giving us control of life cycle management of the injected dependencies. -- It's definitely not overkill for us.

Comment: The only "problem" DI containers are supposed to be used for is to compose applications. Your *applications* that use the libraries are supposed to determine what [runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) to supply to the application (for which user info clearly is). Unity should only be used in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of each application, not in a library.

Comment: A lot of extra code to rewrite? Where? It saves you from having to add code *everywhere in your application* to check whether your dependency is `null`, which is clearly what the problem is here. Generally, for most unit tests, you can make one shared method to populate the dependencies with mocks and then call that method to create your target class instance with all dependencies, so you don't need a lot of code to do this.

Comment: Obviously each application in our solution only has a single stand alone root where we register all of our dependencies, specify their life cycles, etc. -- I'm not sure how this is relevant to the question I asked though? -- We don't have any stand alone class libraries, it's just shared business logic that the various parts of our solution uses. -- If we could get back on topic, I would appreciate it.

Comment: My point is, your *test project* will not have a composition root, and usually won't be concerned with lifetime management (you should do this in your application only). Each unit test is creating a *single* class and its dependencies are usually mocked or stubbed. There is no reason at all to involve a DI container in the process. The DI container is for *composing the application*, it has nothing at all to do with unit tests - why do you think you need a DI container to create 1 class and its mock dependencies for a set of unit tests? Lifetime only comes into play for integration tests.

Comment: I am not sure how I could be more on topic than this. Your question is about using Moq and Unity together somehow. My answer is that your test project shouldn't even have a reference to Unity. There is no good solution for this because this is a situation that should not exist in your test project. It is unclear why you think need a DI container for unit tests in the first place, because Moq should be used for everything except for the class under test anyway.

Comment: Dude, you're arguing philosophy. -- Forget I'm using Unity, and now I'm suddenly injecting all of these parameters manually via the constructor -- or that it comes prebuilt from a factory -- or my mock class magically appears via some other method; -- Bottom line, my mock class comes to me pre-constructed. -- Now I want to intercept calls that are made to this pre-existing/pre-constructed mock object; I want to intercept these calls, so as to verify that it's methods and properties were called as I expect (as if it were a `Mock<T>` created by Moq). -- How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I quite disagree here. I find using DI with unit tests makes my test code smaller and easier to read. And it tests my class under conditions that are closer to real-world. YMMV, but I don't think using DI or not using DI is a matter to be prescriptive about. It's more a matter of preference.